# Load a page with JS in it into a div of another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, latex

I have a page where I load another page into this page div section:

```
<doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>TCS</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-    ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://latex.codecogs.com/latexit.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> LatexIT.add('p',true)</script>
<script>
$(function() {
   $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
   $( "#tabs-1" ).load("b.html");
   $( "#tabs-2" ).load("latex.html");
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="tabs">
<ul>
<li><a href="#tabs-1">Start</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-2">Latex/a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-3">aaa</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1">
</div>
<div id="tabs-2">
</div>
<div id="tabs-3">
</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

So, I load latex.html in it with next code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://latex.codecogs.com/latexit.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
LatexIT.add('p',true);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1><p>Dividing $x^2+1$ by $y^2$ gives \[\frac{x^2+1}{y^2}\]</p></h1>
<p>The british pound is worth 1.5 US\$ or $1.1 \euro$</p>
</body>
</html>
```

If I load this page separately, I get correct Latex expressions, while if I load it into div I get pure text like [\frac{} and so on. What is the problem and a correct way to make it?

Comment: I have it all working...i'm writing my answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Index page code:

```
    <doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>TCS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://latex.codecogs.com/latexit.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> LatexIT.add('p',true)</script>
    <script>
    $(function() {
       $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
       $( "#tabs-1" ).load("latex.html");

    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="tabs">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Latext</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">aaa</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
    </div>
    </div>


    </body>
    </html>
```

On latex.html page just put this(i remove all the other html tags):

```
<h1><p>Dividing $x^2+1$ by $y^2$ gives \[\frac{x^2+1}{y^2}\]</p></h1>
<p>The british pound is worth 1.5 US\$ or $1.1 \euro$</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
$( "#tabs-2" ).load("latex.html", function(){
    LatexIT.add('p',true);
});
```